# Joining rows from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables Table1 and Table2. I wanted to join the two tables data based on the TIME_STAMP data field

I have tried the below query but I am not able to get the expected result

Table 1

```
CATEGORY_ID   ID   TIME_STAMP   VALUE
-------------------------------------
1            444   30-Mar-17    XXX
1            444   31-Jul-18    YYY
1            444   15-Jan-19    ZZZ
```

Table 2

```
CATEGORY_ID  ID    TIME_STAMP   VALUE
------------------------------------------
2           444    30-Mar-17    10/31/2017
2           444    30-May-18    10/25/2018
2           444    13-Jun-19    10/25/2018
```

Actual Result:

```
TIME_STAMP    Table 1 VALUE   Table 2 value
-------------------------------------------
30-Mar-17     XXX               10/31/2017
31-Jul-18     YYY               NULL
15-Jan-19     ZZZ               NULL
```

Query :

```
SELECT
      T1.TIME_STAMP ,
      T1.X_VALUE,
      T2.X_VALUE
FROM
      TABLE1 T1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
      AND 
       TO_CHAR(T1.TIME_STAMP,'MM/DD/YYYY')
      =TO_CHAR(T2.TIME_STAMP,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
      AND 
      T2.CATEGORY_ID=2

WHERE 
      T1.CATEGORY_ID =1 AND T1.ID= 444
```

Expected Result:

```
TIME_STAMP   Table1 VALUE   Table2 VALUE
-----------------------------------------
30-Mar-17    XXX            10/31/2017
30-May-18    NULL           10/25/2018
31-Jul-18    YYY            NULL
15-Jan-19    ZZZ            NULL
13-Jun-19    NULL           10/25/2018
```

Comment: Which variant of SQL are you using? (MySQL, MSSQL, etc.)

Comment: @Kei : I am using Oracle

Answer (score 1):

`FULL OUTER JOIN` with filtering is tricky.  I recommend using a subquery for the filtering criteria:

```
select coalesce(t1.time_stamp, t2.time_stamp) as time_stamp,
       t1.x_value, t2.x_value
from (select t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t1.CATEGORY_ID = 1 and T1.ID = 444
     ) t1 full join
     (select t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.id = 444 and t2.category_id = 2
     ) t2
     on t2.id = t1.id and
        trunc(t2.time_stamp) = trunc(t1.time_stamp);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff , It's perfectly working . Can you please suggest me ,if I have another table(Total 3 tables like Table1,Table2 and Table3) with the same design with different CATEGORY_ID data. How can I add that condition to the subquery.

Comment: @NizamMuhammed . . . You would just add another subquery and another `JOIN`.  If you don't see how to do that, you can ask a new question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected result I think you want to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on the `TIME_STAMP` column.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(t1.time_stamp, t2.time_stamp) AS TIME_STAMP,
       t1.value as T1_value,
       t2.value as T2_value
FROM   table01 t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN table02 t2 ON t1.time_stamp = t2.time_stamp
```

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| TIME_STAMP  | T1_value  |  T2_value  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| 2017-03-30  | XXX       | 10/31/2017 |
| 2018-07-31  | YYY       | (null)     |
| 2019-01-15  | ZZZ       | (null)     |
| 2018-05-30  | (null)    | 10/25/2018 |
| 2019-06-13  | (null)    | 10/25/2018 |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

<sup>Note: I have used SQL Server since you haven't mentioned a DBMS.</sup>

Comment: Thanks @DxTx :  for your time and query. I tried the above query but I am getting other data which is of other time stamp. Do I no need to mentioned the CATEGORY_ID and ID?.As there is other categories data also in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

before you join the two tables with timestamp, you need trunc the timestamp to Date.
like TRUNC("TimeStamp", DATE)

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.time_stamp, t2.time_stamp) AS TIME_STAMP,
   t1.value as T1_value,
   t2.value as T2_value
FROM table01 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table02 t2 
ON trunc(t1.time_stamp, 'DATE') = trunc(t2.time_stamp, 'DATE');
```

Comment: I have used "TO_CHAR(T1.TIME_STAMP,'MM/DD/YYYY') " as it is a oracle but still it display other data . As i also need to put the condition for CATEGORY_ID and ID. Please suggest and Thank you .